# Windows certificate templates: how to include group (or OU) claims in SSL/TLS client certiifcates

Tags: windows, certificate-authority

I'm using X.509 client certificates to authenticate a set of Windows clients via mutual TLS. Which clients are part of this set *should* somehow be administered in AD, e.g. via group membership or parent OU.

Note: The question applies to computer certificates, not to user certificates. I.e. any user should be able to use this certificate when starting a HTTPS request from such a computer. (This is in addition to any user logon method, which is not part of the mTLS authentication scheme.)

Servers should be able to tell that the authenticating client computer is a member of this set. Servers are Linux-based containers and not part of the AD/domain, so all we have is the info in the X.509 certificate.

Do Windows certificate templates provide any method to convey such a claim as part of the X.509 certificate?
It seems I can limit the set of computers that can get such a certificate, but then I don't find a way to mark these certificates in a way that allows the servr to identify them.

- The X.509 certificate does not contain the administrative template name or ID, so I can't set the server to check it either.
- There seems to be limited flexibility in configuring subjects, specifically no method to map any AD information into the subject field. That would be ideal - am I missing something here?
- I was thinking about using a specific intermediate CA for these templates, but that seems way too complicated for such a basic requirements.

Maybe there is another aspect of the X.509 certificate that can be set through the template? Or can I use a different claim than group/OU?

Comment: I was probably asking the wrong question, see https://serverfault.com/questions/1048505/windows-certificate-templates-how-to-make-certificates-from-certain-templates-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. Group membership is rather dynamic property, not static and not part of certificate holder's identity. As the result, you cannot include group membership into a certificate, because this information doesn't belong to identity. And every time group membership is changed, you have to reissue certificate. Certificates are valid for quite long period. This is a very flawed solution.

> I.e. any user should be able to use this certificate when starting a HTTPS request from such a computer

this will work only when TLS request is sent from an application that runs under local system or network service account. If you want to use such certificates, you have to explicitly configure TLS client to use non-default client certificate via source code, for example.

> Servers are Linux-based containers and not part of the AD/domain

interesting, how Linux-based servers are supposed to validate actual group membership?

Client certificate in mutual TLS is authentication method. Fields in certificate are mapped to account information servers must be connected to.

Since your Linux servers aren't part of any AD, then they cannot bind client certificate to AD user account and validate group membership. Servers even cannot tell if such group really exist. There must be a separate identity database available to Linux servers and Linux servers must somehow bind client certificate to identity in that separate identity database. And only information available in this separate identity database shall be used for client authorization.

This means that your requirements:

> Group membership for computers should be administered in AD.

and

> Servers are Linux-based containers and not part of the AD/domain

are mutually exclusive and cannot be used together. Either, make Linux server AD-aware or include in certificates information about identity which is available to Linux servers. And I would strongly avoid group membership inclusion in certificates. Group membership should be used in short-lived tokens, not in long-lived certificates.

Comment: Thank you. However, I'm looking for a solution to a specific technical requirement here, not explaining my whole scenario end-to-end, so I can't quite agree with some of your a priory assessements. 

If I can get a group membership *at the time off issuance* into the certificate, it becomes a claim that I can somehow evaluate at the server side. That does not mean that the server must know about group memberships, those would only be a means to set this claim.

Yes, certificate lifetime is an issue. However, lifetime can be controlled, and these machines would not get re-purposed anyway.

Comment: `If I can get a group membership at the time off issuance` -- as I said, group membership is not part of identity, here is the problem. Name is part of identity, last name, user principal name, SID -- these are parts of identity. Groups aren't. And you even can't verify this information on server side, because your servers are not connected to AD.

Comment: Not sure why you insist that I cannot verify on server side. I can acutally verify anything oh the server side that's included in the certificate, if I  control the server.

Comment: While it's true that group membership is not part of identity, it's not uncommon to issue certificate that contain an implicit claim by just being issued. That's all I'm asking for - and a way to recognize these certificates on the server side.

Comment: You said that Linux servers (which suppose to validate certs from Windows clients) aren't connected to AD, thus they can't validate group membership. Otherwise, you present a claim no one can verify. It is an anti-pattern. I would suggest to revisit your AAA model. At this point I can't help you apart from what I already said.

Comment: I believe my question was worded to closely along a possible solution I was hoping for. I overstated the group membership, and it seems you are reading even more into it beyond that. So 1) I cleared up the question here, but that probably won't change the answer, so 2) I'm posting a more appropriate one https://serverfault.com/questions/1048505/windows-certificate-templates-how-to-make-certificates-from-certain-templates-r