# Windows certificate templates: how to make certificates from certain templates recognizable

Tags: windows, certificate-authority

I'm using X.509 client certificates to authenticate a well-defined set of Windows clients via mutual TLS. A certificate template exists that issues this type of certificate to all clients in this set, but not to others.

On the server side, I can run code that evaluates the X.509 certificate to see if it was issued by this template.

However, the template name or ID are not part of the X.509 data.

Is there any other way to put unique information into the certificate via the template? E.g.

- modify the subject (e.g. to include some generic AD attribute or a fixed value)
- add or modify another x.590 certificate property

It seems I can achieve this using

- issuing the certificate from a specific intermediate CA (easy to verify on server via trusted root list)
- using a custom key usage extension (would need specific code on the server side)

However, both of these methods would be rather difficult to deploy.

(This is a follow up to [Windows certificate templates: how to include group (or OU) claims in SSL/TLS client certiifcates](https://serverfault.com/questions/1048479/windows-certificate-templates-how-to-include-group-or-ou-claims-in-ssl-tls-cl) where I was probably asking the wrong question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, the template name or ID are not part of the X.509 data.

It turns out that's wrong, I just missed it.

The template ID and version are encoded in OID [1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.7](http://oidref.com/1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.7) as defined by [MS-WCEE 2.2.2.7.7.2 szOID_CERTIFICATE_TEMPLATE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-wcce/9da866e5-9ce9-4a83-9064-0d20af8b2ccf)